# Are setState's updater arguments always identical to this.state and this.props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

`setState` has [a form that accepts a callback `updater`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). This `updater` is invoked when this state transition actually occurs (since `setState` may be asynchronous), accepting `state` and `props` of the component as explicit arguments at the time of state setting. Is there any difference to referring to these arguments vs. `this.state` and `this.props`? [The docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) say:

> That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument.

My motivation to know is that I have some pure functions of props and state in this component to calculate some derived values that are sometimes fed back into state. I'd like to avoid rewriting these functions when they're needed in `setState`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big difference is that `this.state` will only update *after* all currently queued `setState` calls have finished:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.increment(); this.increment(); }}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

If the `this.state` updated immediately, you'd see the count jump from 0 to 2 to 4, etc, but it doesn't; it updates one-by-one, because `this.state` doesn't update immediately.

In contrast, using the callback form's argument *does* provide you with the possibly-just-updated value.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  increment() {
    this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.increment(); this.increment(); }}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```